# Creating folder in already existing folder

Tags: java

I am trying to create new folder in already existing folder, existing folder is given by application at the beginning and by default I will name it 'File Manager' and will be stored directly on C:\ root (example: C:\File Manager). First I create code that is allowing user to name new folder by:

```
        System.out.println("Enter name of folder you like to create: ");
        Scanner userFolderInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nameFolder = userFolderInput.nextLine();
        File makeDirectory = new File(nameFolder);
```

then I am checking if folder that user gave name already exist and try to create it by:

```
        try{
            if(!makeDirectory.exists()){
                makeDirectory.mkdir();
                System.out.println("You have create folder by name: " + makeDirectory.getName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Folder by name " + makeDirectory.getName() + " already exist!");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error - Folder coudnt be created!");
        }
```

but this only creates new folder input by user in folder of project but not in folder that application made it on start. May I know how to modify my code so when user creates new folder goes in File Manager folder created at the start of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File containingFolder = new File("C:/File Manager");
File makeDirectory = new File(containingFolder, nameFolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify a path, it will automatically create it in the project directory. So when the user inputs the name of the folder, you need to add to it the path where it needs to be created.

```
     File makeDirectory = new File("C:\\"+nameFolder);
```

OR

```
File makeDirectory = new File(fileManager, nameFolder);
```

Comment: thank you for quick responds. When I try that all it does it creates new folder directly to C:\\ root, if I add name of default folder as FIle makeDirectory = new File("C:\\File Manager ", + nameFolder); that it creates new folder on C:\ root name 'File Manager new folder name' but doesn't put it on folder that I want.

Comment: You are welcome Denis. Note that in stackoverflow you cannot accept 2 answers. So since you accepted the second answer after mine, I loose the +15 reputation points that you gave me.

Comment: oh... I apologize about it, it is my first time on stackoverflow and well both answers help me finding solution and I want it to accept both answers as right ones. I notice that mistake after I did it. I will have to be very careful n future. Sorry again.

Comment: It's ok. You can still accept my answer again since I was the first to answer.